# Raspberry pi running owncloud not reachable using no-ip URL

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, nginx

I have a problem reaching my raspberry pi from outside of my LAN and I don't remember having changed anything. It was working previously, but I don't know what changed.

I've installed `owncloud` with `nginx` and `mysql` over HTTPS. If I try to access the server using it's local IP address everything works fine. Using the official URL with no-ip.biz spins for a while but ends in a blank page without any error.

Do you have any ideas how to solve the issue?

I recently updated the system but can't remember what might have changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your no-ip client isn't running? The [installation instructions](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/) says "Read the README file in the no-ip-2.1.9 folder for instructions on how to make the client run at startup."
If your Raspberry have been rebooted and doesn't start automatically, you would be able to access ownCloud on your local network address, but not through the no-ip.com address.

Another possibility: When you sign up for a free account at no-ip.com, the term says that you have to [reactivate your account every 30 days](https://www.noip.com/remote-access). This wouldn't be a unix issue, but could be the answer to your question?